# Running BLAST+ BLASTn with accession numbers from a list

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I want to BLASTn several sequences against a reference genome using NCBI BLAST+ and output only the line with the accession number, E-value, and other information on it from the BLAST+ output (because there are several extraneous lines from the BLAST+ output) to a csv.  I have these files:

Text file with accession numbers for human gene sequences, one per line:  **GSEA-toBLASTaccession.txt**

Reference genome:  **botznik-chr.fa**

Output csv: **GSEABLAST.csv**

Here is the code I have written to execute this:

```
for acc in `cat GSEA-toBLASTaccession.txt`; do
    echo $acc | blastn -db botznik-chr.fa -out GSEABLAST.out -num_alignments 1 \
    -outfmt "6 qacc evalue qstart qend sstart send bitscore score length pident \
    nident ppos positive mismatch gapopen" >> GSEABLAST.csv
done
```

I am not getting the results I need from this; what do I need to tweak to get a CSV with the accession number, E-value, query start/end, sequence start/end, bitscore, score, length, identity %/number, positive %/number, mismatch, and gap/open on it for a BLAST for each of the genes in my list of accession numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe the output that you do get so it requires some guesswork to figure out what the problem is. I suspect that you're expecting the output for all sequences to be in `GSEABLAST.csv` but instead you're getting the output from only the last sequence in `GSEABLAST.out`

If that is the problem, it's because `-out GSEABLAST.out` causes the output to be sent to the specified file rather than to STDOUT. This file gets overwritten with every iteration of the `for` loop. If you remove that part of the command, the output will go to STDOUT which is then appended to `GSEABLAST.csv`